# Convert a Website with a responsive design to the Android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, html

I want to make an Android App without much effort. I already have a website with a responsive design. Is there an easy way to convert it or maybe display a website as an Android app?

Comment: What is the point of an app that is basically a bookmark with app icon?

Comment: @good_evening Hi, how did you managed to do it? Using WebView with PhoneGap or something else? I need similar thing to do, please advise

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to go the minimal effort route, why not just create an application with a single [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) using a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Here is a guide from Google on [developing Web Apps in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Answer (score 3):

By making your web site responsive, i don't think that you need to convert or display your website as a native App. I think that you need a real mobile or android user experience to get the satisfactions of users.

A lot of technical solution exists already like using a [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your first activity.

But, my advice, is to make a dedicated design for your app and to apply a full android user experience for it.

Good luck